# Very fast parser (php) for huge xml-feeds

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, simplepie

I need a very fast php parsing implementation for parsing huge xml-feeeds on the fly, it would be very important that the parser starts parsing when the data comes in, not only when the whole feed is downloaded. I tried simplepie but still looking for something faster! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the PHP XML parser you can parse chunk by chunk: http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse.php

So you can load the XML file line by line and push it to your XML parser. Without any surrounding framework, I expect this to be the fastest.

I'm not sure what will happen if you load the XML directly by http://…, if it is possible to read the content before the whole file is loaded.

Comment: Looks good too. maybe even better? I never used it. The API looks more comfortable than XML parser. XMLReader stops on every node. With the XML Parser you can define just a few elements you want to interrupt. So XMLReader is maybe simpler and XML Parser more "hardcore" and so maybe faster.

Comment: my, speed and memory footprint would definetly uoverrule simplicity, would be worth the effort of writing the code. So you think xml parser would fit these criteria more than xmlreader? i need to parser the wholee feed (means every item, will be 300 for each feed, that multiplied by 13-15 feeds)

Comment: To be honest, I don't now. The XML Parser works more directly on the strings. With XMLReader I'm not sure if they maybe load first the whole or big parts of the document. SAX and XML Parser is the same, I guess?